# Cannot filter Directories with Powershell using an environment variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, get-childitem

I have come across an unexpected behaviour when trying to filter a list of directories set in an environment variable array.

When I run this code using a local variable I get the expected result:

```
$myPath = "C:\temp\"
$myList = 'Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'
Write-Host "myList: $myList" 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $myPath | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $myList } | Select-Object FullName
```

i.e.

```
myList: Folder1 Folder2 Folder3

FullName
--------
C:\temp\Folder1
C:\temp\Folder2
C:\temp\Folder3
```

However when I replace `$myList` with an environment variable `$env:yourList`

```
$myPath = "C:\temp\"
$env:yourList = 'Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'
Write-Host "yourList: $env:yourList"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $myPath | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $env:yourList } | Select-Object FullName
```

the result of Get-ChildItem is empty

```
yourList: Folder1 Folder2 Folder3
.
```

As you can see from the output above the value set in `$env:yourList` is printed identical to the one set in `$myList`, so what's so special about **environment variables** that causes them to be processed differently in Where-Object criteria?

BTW, the same behaviour occurs when using `-Include` instead of `Where-Object`, i.e.:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath -Recurse -Include $env:yourList -Directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An *environment* variable is always a *single string***, so you cannot store *arrays* in them (or any other data types other than `[string]`).

- Note: This is outside of PowerShell's control: environment variables are a system-level feature.

PowerShell *stringifies* the input array on *assignment*<sup>[1]</sup>, which means joining the array elements with a space as the separator (or, if defined, the separator stored in preference variable `$OFS`), which is why array `'Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'` turned into single string
`'Folder1 Folder2 Folder3'`.

---

If you really do need an *environment* variable to store your array - which is normally only needed for communicating values to *child processes* - you'll have to choose a single-string representation for it on *assignment*, which you can re-convert to an array on *reading* the variable; e.g.:

```
# Assuming the array elements contain no newlines, use newlines
# to separate them.
$env:yourList = ('Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3') -join "`n"

# Later, re-convert the single-string representation to an array.
$env:yourList -split "`n"
```

---

<sup>[1] As [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer) points out, this *automatic to-string conversion* happens with *any* RHS that isn't already of type `[string]`, such as with `$env:yourList = 42` (assigns string `'42'`). In other words: **Anything you assign to an environment variable is automatically converted to a (single) string.**</sup>

Comment: Even if you try `$env:yourList = [int]1` you won't get an error but the type is still `$env:yourList.gettype().name    String`  Big fan mklement0

Comment: Indeed, @DougMaurer - PowerShell happily and automatically converts any data type to `[string]`, which all environment variables are implicitly typed as. Thanks for the nice feedback.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense, I have to use environment variables as this is a ps script within an Azure DevOps pipeline and I need to set the list in the pipeline variables.